# Passing a prop to a different element appears to be done properly yet the prop is never recognized by the receiving element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am building a React app that handles file encryption and decryption. I am stuck in the part of naming a file. So far I had the app name every exported decrypted file as "Decrypted_File", but I am trying to change this by retaining the initial file's name and concatenating "_decrypted.txt".

*User drops a file here*

```
  const onDrop = async (acceptedFiles) => {
    try {
      const droppedFile = acceptedFiles[0];
      const encryptedFileName = droppedFile.name; // Save the name of the dropped file
      const text = await droppedFile.text();
      setFile({ content: text, name: droppedFile.name });
      setFileDecrypted(false);
      setDecryptedContent(null); // Reset the decrypted content when a new file is selected
      createDecryptedFile(encryptedFileName);
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

*File is generated here*

```
  const createDecryptedFile = (decryptedContent, encryptedFileName) => {
    if (decryptedContent) {
      const decryptedBlob = new Blob([decryptedContent], { type: 'text/plain' });
      const decryptedFileName = encryptedFileName + '_decrypted.txt';

      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(decryptedBlob);
      link.download = decryptedFileName;

      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  };
```

The prop appears to be filled in properly, yet it appears unused on the IDE and the result is not what I expect. Instead of pushing a file the way I intend, it pushes a file named "undefined_decrypted.txt" which is also void of content.

Comment: Where are you calling to the createDecryptedFile function? What is the line 51?

Comment: It is       const encryptedFileName = droppedFile.name; // Save the name of the dropped file that is never used. It is supposed to go to createDecryptedFile() as a prop and being used in there but it never reaches it.

Comment: The eslint warning is ok. You are defining a variable that you are not using it. I still don't see where are you calling to the createDecryptedFile function

Comment: You are right. I edited it but the file name is still not properly parsed. The downloaded file is now called "[object Object]_encrypted.txt".

Comment: Here: createDecryptedFile(encryptedFileName); you are only passing one argument but in the function definition you are waiting two arguments. You are missing the second argument, which is the name.